# How to get a line matches Parenthesis in DevExpress in visualstudio?

Tags: visual-studio, devexpress

I am new to DevExpress.
In code rush

```
Public Method()
{
.
.
.
}
```

In between { and } one line mark is showing earlier for matching Parenthesis.
Suddenly it disappears.

How to get it back. ?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember CodeRush having this by default. Here is what I use: https://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/wiki/CR_BlockPainterPlus